# CoreData: 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '+entityForName: could not locate an entity named 'DocumentLocations' in this model.'

Tags: xcode, core-data, model, entity

I've suddenly been tripped up by a bizarre issue.  I have a rather extensive CoreData data model, and I've copied it (and the project containing it) over to a new project for a prototype that I'm working on.  I got it working, and was mixing and matching new entities and attributes.

Suddenly, and for no apparent reason, I'm suddenly getting the following error:

> 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '+entityForName: 
>   could not locate an entity named 'DocumentLocations' in this model.'

I dug into the whole process for creating the NSManagedObjectContext, NSPersistentStoreCoordinator, and NSManagedObjectModel, and have gotten to the point where it's pretty clear that the object model is not being loaded.  I execute the following command:

> _managedObjectModel = [[NSManagedObjectModel mergedModelFromBundles:nil] retain];

But when I look for the entities in the model after loading (this method creates the model from the main bundle if you pass nil to mergedModelFromBundles), nothing's there.

It appears that my xdatamodel file is not being seen by Xcode or the Simulator.  And I have absolutely no idea why not.  I'm going to try to force the issue by explicitly loading it through a URL, but I'm not sure how that's going to work.

Any clues?  CoreData issues can be absolutely baffling.  I've managed to work my way through most of them over time, but this one's a head-scratcher.

Edit: Alex figured it out.  I'm only left with wondering how the model got removed from the 'Compile Sources' list in Xcode.  Wish Xcode were more reliable.  Can really be a PITA.

Comment: Are you sure the xcdatamodel is being copied into your app? Just adding it to the project may not be enough, so you may also need to check your build settings to make sure it's being included. You could also track down your built .app bundle on the file system and open it  up to see if the data model files are included.

Comment: Wow.  That was brilliant.  My only question is:  how the hell did it get removed????

Thanks a ton.  Wish I'd figured that out yesterday.  Would've saved me an enormous amount of time.  Now I get to go back and debug my /other/ issues!

Thanks again.

Comment: Add the datamodel file to the current build target (sidebar right)

Comment: @MartinBrugger Yes.  I did that once Alex identified what the problem was.  And it worked.  I just don't understand how it got removed in the first place.  As far as I can tell, I did nothing to facilitate this.  I always assume EBSAK, but sometimes Xcode will behave in ... _oddly_....

Comment: How do I identify @Alex's answer as correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Alex figured it out.  For some reason, the xdatamodel was removed from the build settings.  I added it back in and it worked.  I don't really understand why it would have been removed in the first place.  It literally disappeared between one build and the next.

Answer (score 2):

Fixed this by deleting the app - from the simulator and my iPhone.

Apparently the DB was added without the entities in an early run.  Then, once I added the entities and wired everything up, started receiving an error similar to above...

Deleting the app allowed the DB to be recreated and fixed the problem.