# Re-add the xcdatamodel to the Build Settings

Tags: ios, core-data, xcdatamodel

While I was busy trying out stuff for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19387877/add-many-attributes-to-my-xdatamodel-ios-core-data), I accidently removed the xcdatamodel-package.

I found out that recently there was [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7666297/coredata-nsinternalinconsistencyexception-reason-entityforname-could-not/7759802#7759802) which mentioned the following:

> *For some reason, the xdatamodel was removed from the build settings. I added it back in and it worked.*

I tried doing what he did, but I don't know where to start.

I recreated the package, but when I try to set an attribute value, I get **+entityForName: could not locate an entity named 'EN'...**

All I know is; it did work until I started fooling around with not-tutorial-attributes and stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What they're getting at in that other question is that when you add a file to a project, it's not necessarily added to the current target. You can have multiple targets in a project, and you can add files that don't get compiled (e.g. developer documentation), so it's possible to add a file but then have it just sit there and not get built.

If you select the file in Xcode and open up the Utilities pane on the right, there's a section that shows target membership. It looks like this:

[image: target membership]

This one shows that the file belongs to the project `momdecTests` but not to the project `momdec`. Make sure your app target is checked here.

Comment: Thanks! I hoped it was just the lack of membership, but it now shows it already had membership. Any ideas on the error then?

Comment: Maybe you're not creating an instance of `NSManagedObjectModel`? Hard to say without more detail about the project and its code.

Comment: [Some details](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19390501/entityforname-could-not-locate-an-entity-named-entityname) ;)