# +entityForName: could not locate an entity named 'Entityname'

Tags: ios, core-data

I got this little part of code:

```
nwtAppDelegate *appDelegate =(nwtAppDelegate *) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

NSManagedObjectContext *context =
[appDelegate managedObjectContext];
NSManagedObject *newContact;
newContact = [NSEntityDescription
              insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"EN"
              inManagedObjectContext:context];
[newContact setValue:@"laaa" forKey:@"b_1_1"];
NSError *error;
[context save:&error];
```

But I get this error **+entityForName: could not locate an entity named 'Entityname'**.

The entity, and the attributes do exist.

**Diagram:**

[image]

Comment: Please post your entity diagram

Comment: Do you actually have a valid reference to the MOC or is it nil ?

Comment: @Wain, I don't know.. how do I check that?

Comment: Check if the context is nil, and also that the model your appDelegate is loading is the same model you are working with.

Comment: NSLog of the context gives **<NSManagedObjectContext: 0x89bfe00>** (?)

Comment: This suggests that something's broken in your Core Data stack. Maybe you never created an `NSManagedObjectModel`, or you created one but didn't assign its persistent store coordinator attribute, or your `NSPersistentStoreCoordinator` is nil, or maybe something else. Or maybe you mis-typed the name of the model file in the code.

Comment: I have pretty much the same problem and the same NSLog context result. I've tried multiple stacks but still have the same problem: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24676575/osx-coredata-issue-only-for-some-entities-entityforname-could-not-locate-an